# I have just installed android studio and emulator is not working 3.6.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have just completed a fresh install of android studio and I have created a virtual device I am trying to start android virtual device but I am getting this error.

Emulator: C:\android_sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an AVD with a lower API level that just worked for me