# Android Studio - error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to run the Android Studio emulator on my PC and keep getting the above error regardless of what device / API I'm using.

I have read about a similar problem in other posts: [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61243837/i-have-just-installed-android-studio-and-emulator-is-not-working-3-6-2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023481/android-emulator-error-while-loading-state-for-instance-0x0-of-device-goldfis), but despite making sure I have the most up to date HAXM and trying various versions / wiping the device storage, nothing seems to work.

Other potential fixes I have tried include:

1. Delete all virtual devices
2. Manual device launch / reset
3. Launch from cold boot
4. Delete SDK folder manually before redownloading devices.
5. Installed various devices and API versions.
6. Manually install latest version of HAXM and validate it is installed.
7. Adjust the number of CPU cores being used in the device config.

Comment: After installing these have you restarted your machine and run android studio as an administrator, that is if you are running android studio in a windows environment.

Comment: I have done both of these, yes @George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have Valorant game , Stop Riot vanguard.
When Vanguard is active it will immediatly terminate your Android Emulation even with a Cold Boot.

Comment: Wow... I think this is right. I noticed it randomly started working again and it was after I temporarily uninstalled Valorant. Thank you!